# How do I interpret swift (or general) closure in call stack in assembly?

Tags: swift, assembly, closures

```
class Assembly {
    func getThis(value: Int) -> () -> () {
        var a = value

        return {
            a += 1
            print(a)
        }
    }
}

let assembly = Assembly()

let first = assembly.getThis(value: 5)
first()
first()

let second = assembly.getThis(value: 0)
second()
second()

first()
second()
```

gives value of:

```
6
7
1
2
8
3
```

I understand this is expected and I just want to understand how this works. I know the basics of how stack works in assembly. I think when `getThis` called, a new stack frame is pushed and allocate local variable `a` by assigning `value`.

But does this stack frame get popped? It looks like it does, because it returns a value means the function has finished. But on the other hand, if the stack frame is popped, the local variable on the stack frame is gone, means the `a` will be deallocated, obviously this isn't the case.

So how does this whole thing work?

Comment: It probably creates a structure to represent the closure that contains both the address of the nested function and a pointer to its captured values, which would be allocated on the heap not the stack. When the closure is called the pointer to its captured values is passed as a hidden argument to the nested function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very large "gap" between Swift code and assembly code. The transformation between these two languages is *vast*, so I recommend you not to think "Oh wait, that wouldn't work in assembly!" because compilers are much smarter than you might think.

What basically happens here is, the closure retuned by `getThis` *captures* the local variable `a`. This means that `a` kind of "went inside" the closure. The closure now has state. This happens whenever you use `self` or a local variable in a closure.

How is this achieved at a low-level of abstraction? I am not really sure about how exactly the compiler works, but this kind of capturing of variables is usually done with a state machine of some kind. Therefore, your statement about `a` getting deallocated when `getThis` returns is probably not true. `a` will stay in memory, because it is retained by the closure. How does it do this? I can only tell you "compiler magic".

Anyway, how else do you want `first` to behave? Undefined behaviour? That doesn't sound Swifty. Resetting `a` to 0 every time you call `first`? That's no different from declaring a new variable again in `first`, is it? At the end of the day, it just seems like this "capturing" semantics is a useful thing to have in the language, so they designed Swift like so.